# How invoke a function given its name in string in Lua/Torch?

Tags: python, matlab, lua, eval, torch

I want to evaluate a string name as a function in Lua/Torch. Below is an example of what I want to do:

```
require 'torch'

tensorType = torch.getdefaulttensortype()
print (tensorType) -- Will print "torch.DoubleTensor"
```

My goal is to be able to use the string in `tensorType` as name of a function and evaluate that function like follow:

```
tensorType(some arguments)
```

In MATLAB and Python there is a `eval()' function which can execute arbitrary strings. Is there such a function in Lua/Torch?

How can I do that in Torch/Lua?

Comment: Please explain more. Functions don't have names. "torch.DoubleTensor" is not an identifier, anyway. Do you mean it is an expression? Would "torch" be a global variable?

Comment: @TomBlodget I don't clearly understand what you mean, but as far as I know functions have names (like the example given in the question). I think you do not have "Torch" installed on your machine. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry for being so terse. A function is a value that is referenced by one or more variables. If you have a value that you believe is a function, you can try to call it. So, that part becomes unimportant. The question is what do you mean by "torch.DoubleTensor". Based on your comments, you want a general answer. It looks like an identifier, dot, identifier. That could be an expression to which an indexing operation is performed with the index (key) as a string (the 2nd identifier). @lhf showed how to use that— assuming "torch" is a variable in scope, which if it was a global, it would be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loadstring` but that's generally not recommended because it has to compile code at runtime. What is this for?

Comment: I want to be able to dynamically switch between data types while the program is running.

Comment: @Amir I don't understand?

Comment: So in my program I have a table whose entries include data from different data types. When the program runs with some default data type (e.g. torch.DoubleTensor), I need to convert the data in my table to the default data type.

Comment: @Amir How do you expect to convert them? What datatypes are you converting?

Comment: They are in float, double and int.

Comment: @Amir So you need to run methods by string because? How does that apply to your question?

Comment: Well because on each run of the program I have to convert the dats to the default data type and the default data type might also change while the program is running.

Comment: By the way, look at the title of the question. It is meant to be general

Comment: @Your question doesn't make sense. Perhaps rewriting it will help?

Answer (score 1):

First extract the name of the field from the string:

```
k=tensorType:match("%.(.+)$")
```

Then use the name to call the function:

```
torch[k](some arguments)
```

Comment: Thanks. But this only works for my problem and is not generalizable. Is there any general way of invoking a function name given its name only?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [lutorpy](https://github.com/imodpasteur/lutorpy), you will have a lua engine in python, thus, you can load any lua/torch library, and you can run lua code with "lua.eval('torch.DoubleTensor(3,4)')". Check [lutorpy](https://github.com/imodpasteur/lutorpy) for more details.